# What are callable objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know that callable objects are like functions which are created as objects and can be used in a function invocation expression.
But how can one distinguish between a callable object and normal function?

Comment: Can you give an example of a “callable object”?

Comment: Probably an example will help us to understand question clearly

Comment: The spec talks about an `IsCallable()` test, which returns true for objects implementing the `[[Call]]` internal method. It's useful terminology for discussing the internals, but it's not really interesting as a JavaScript programmer for any practical purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure someone else can give a more comprehensive answer, but basically a callable object is one which you can call, as evidenced by the presence of the `call` function, e.g.:

```
if (func.call) {
    func.call();   
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzaonmgo/

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score -1):

In JS, functions are "object-like" in the sense that they have properties:

```
function f() { return 2; }
f.foo = 3;
console.log(typeof f); // "function"
console.log(f.foo); // 3
```

Apart from that, there really is no such thing as a "callable object" that is not a simple function (except maybe in certain IEs? I don't know), and it's not even possible to do something weird like create an object with a function as its prototype:

```
var obj = Object.create(f);
console.log(obj()); // TypeError: obj is not a function
```